# Filling in the derivative of the absolute value at zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

I have a function $f(x)$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ and
I'm interested in the derivative $\frac{d |f(x)|}{dx}$ evaluated at the point $x_0$.

I realize that this is usually undefined.

However, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}\frac{d |f(x)|}{dx}=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^-}\frac{d |f(x)|}{dx}=0$, is it ok to say that $\frac{d |f(x)|}{dx}=0$ then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the case that $\frac{d|f(x)|}{dx}$ is usually undefined at zeros of the function $f$. For instance, if $f(x) = x^2$, then $|f(x)| = f(x)$, hence $|f(x)|$ is clearly differentiable at $x=0$.

So yes, if the limit of the difference quotient defining the derivative of $|f(x)|$ exists, then $|f(x)|$ is differentiable at that point.

Comment: How about trying to apply the chain-rule. It seems to be that it gets messed up? Perhaps that is a too simplistic view of the derivative in my case...

Comment: You are correct that you cannot apply the chain rule in this case since $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. However, this does not imply that $|f(x)|$ is not differentiable at the point. The chain rule is logically one-way in this sense: it gives us a formula for the derivative of the composition of two differentiable functions, but it does _not_ say that the composition of functions which are not differentiable is itself not differentiable.